# Getting SQL Output in Flyway

Tags: flyway

I have been trying the Flyway Framework recently. It fits very well into my project and everything is so perfect. Now I understand that there is no way we can get the console output from a SQL (Something like the SPOOL command in SQLPlus).

Is there an alternate solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I would think of until this is implemented, would be to supply Flyway with a mock jdbc driver that would write the statements to disk instead of sending them to the db.

Comment: Thanks Axel. We are in the process of evaluating Flyway and Liquibase at the moment. Based on my research I found Flyway to be the best fit for us as we manually perform most of the tasks that Flyway does. The only thing that is preventing us from using Flyway right now is, we try to get the SQL output for all our SQLs (we use SQLDeveloper and it usually gives us the no of rows updated/deleted when we execute updates/deletes - which really means a lot to our team). So it would great if you can implement this soon. Until then we have decided to wait. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey Axel - Just being curious, any idea when this would be implemented.

Comment: I too have the same desire. We track the number of records updated and that is important information for troubleshooting. We also output information about what schema changes were completed and that is also valuable. I have enabled the extended logging with log4j and still do not see that output in the logging. But I have decided to continue to go ahead with using flyway and instead I will write the output message that are important to me to a table in the DB so that those messages can be reviewed later when needed.